# Is there a way to run mongodb_store with mongodb-org?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed the official mongodb-org package and now I try to install mongodb_store. This however requires me to unistall mongodb-org (official) and install mongodb (unofficial ubuntu version). Is it possible to use the content of mongodb_store with mongodb-org? I am on ubuntu 18.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367825/is-there-a-way-to-run-mongodb_store-with-mongodb-org?/) by [stefan_frei](https://answers.ros.org/users/65716/stefan_frei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should absolutely work with mongodb-org. I would assume that the dependencies of the `mongodb_store` package are wrongly stated in that the dependency should be `(mongodb | mongodb-org)` and even that is not quite accurate, it should probably be just the server: `(mongodb-server | mongodb-org-server)`. So I think your issue is just the installation not the usage. You could get around that in several ways by [ignoring unmet dependencies](https://serverfault.com/questions/250224/how-do-i-get-apt-get-to-ignore-some-dependencies), or you might be able to build `mongodb_store` from source.

---

Originally posted by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) with karma: 553 on 2020-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stefan_frei](https://answers.ros.org/users/65716/stefan_frei/) on 2020-12-16**:
Thanks for the answer, however ignoring mongodb does not quite work:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-mongodb-store mongodb-                               
Reading package lists... Done                                                                        
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'mongodb' is not installed, so not removed
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-melodic-mongodb-store : Depends: mongodb but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I will try out to build `mongodb_store` from source.

**Comment by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) on 2020-12-16**:
There were other suggestions in that link. I think the easiest would actually be to download the deb file for `mongodb_store`, unbundle it, change the control file manually to set the dependency as I suggested, rebunde the deb file and install it (details in one of the answers in my link). But building from source might be relatively straightforward as well.